# python django - how to unittest endpoints

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to write django tests to ensure that the login page is available, then to retrieve a test_user, register it in the session and load the authenticated page.
Here is my url.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'myapp.views.index'),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {
        'template_name': 'login.html'
    }),
)
```

and my tests.py

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
class MyPage(TestCase):
    def test_homepage(self):
        #response = self.client.get("accounts/login/")
        response = self.client.get(reverse("/accounts/login/"))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertIn("form", response.context)
```

When I use "reverse", I get this error:
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for '/accounts/login/'
and when I omit "reverse", I get a 404 error.
I would like to know how to fix that?
Also, if someone could elaborate on the test authentication part, I'd appreciate it. It would make this a very useful post.

---

update:
I've tried:

```
response = self.client.post(reverse('login'), {'username': 'name', 'password': 'something'}, follow=True)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        assert not "Failed to login" in response.content, "Failed to login!"
```

I cannot understand why it fails to login.
When I tried sending a post request via fiddler, I got:

> CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
>
> You are seeing this message because this site requires a CSRF cookie
>   when submitting forms. This cookie is required for security reasons,
>   to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.

Any clues as to why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reverse` is for reversing to URL from views or url name AFAIK.

you can do either `reverse('django.contrib.auth.views.login')` or name the url and use the name

`url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {
        'template_name': 'login.html'
    }, name="login"),` and `reverse('login')`

The test client in django also has `login` method to simulate user login.

See:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client